# How to add linkbutton inside datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new in wpf, I'm binded patientid,name,gender, but I need how a hyperlink inside the datagrid of wpf. Please help me to solve

```
<DataGrid.Columns>                
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Patient ID}" Header="Patient ID" Width="120" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Patient Name}" Header="Patient Name" Width="150" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Gender}" Header="Gender" Width="100" />
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="LinkReport">
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.aspx)

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Gender">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding LinkReport}">
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Verymuch helpful thanks Sajeetharan,but it visible as button,hw as a hyperlink